# RayCasting issue in THREE.js — Intersections are temperamental, most of the time returning no intersects

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I'm using the Raycaster in THREE.js to focus on objects with the mouse position. It's something I've done a million times before without issue, but there's something in my current setup which isn't working.

Occasionally, the onFocus callback is fired, but most of the time the onBlur callback is called. As far as I can see from the examples and Stack Overflow questions I'm doing things correctly, but it seems not... The only difference I can see between now and other time's I've done it is that usually my camera is at 0, 0, 0.0001, looking outwards to objects, and this time the camera is above, looking into objects.

The camera is at 130, 325, 194, and the object is at 0, 0, 0.

Code snippets below:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);

const geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff, wireframe: false } );
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.onFocus = () => {
    console.log('focus test');
}
mesh.onBlur = () => {
    console.log('blur test');
}
intersectableObjects.push(mesh);
scene.add(mesh);



const onMouseMove = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    const x = (clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    const y = - (clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    mouseVector.set(x, y);
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouseVector, camera);
    castFocus();
}



const castFocus = () => {
    intersectableObjects.forEach((obj, i) => {
        const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( obj, false );
        if (intersects.length) return obj.onFocus();
        obj.onBlur();
    });
}
```

Comment: you dont have to try to intersect each object individually. you can use `raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );` or you can pass to `raycaster.intersectObjects` your array of objects to test for intersection.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this also but it still doesn't work. I intersect them separately as it makes it a bit easier to work with the onBlur and onFocus callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few very frustrating hours I discovered that the Raycaster has issues when working with a very low value for cameraNear.

I had the camera near set to 0.000001, but when I increased it to 0.01, it worked fine.